# How can I find the associated colour to a specific token in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently seeing a token that I am sure it's parsed by VSCode and the language plugin. I want to change the colour of this token but I have no idea how that token is marked. Is there a way to find more details about the match and trace it back to the actual syntax colour that is being used, so that I can override it?

Comment: look for command containig `Developer` and `Scope`

Comment: @rioV8 I have no idea what that means

Comment: open command palette and type these two words

Comment: @rioV8 I found it, thanks, and I see what the textmate scopes are, but if I add those to the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations", under the theme name, I get an error "Property is not allowed"

Comment: if you don't show your modifications to `settings.json` it is hard to see what the error might be